# I need to deploy all the files in a diff file (txt) to an org Salesforce

Tags: bash, git, version-control, salesforce

I have to deploy from a git Diff to a Salesforce Org.
So I have all the files names written on a txt file and need to bring them all to the Salesforce Org.
The files I have them in local and need to, as I said, deploy them to the Salesforce Org.

I tried doing sfdx and writing them all but it gives me

```
"C:\Program" is not a reconized command
```

I tried adding """ at the start and """ at the end and separating each file with a "","" but it still doesn't work.
I know I can do it from a xml file but I have the diff in a txt.

Comment: This definitely sounds like missing quotes. Try single quoting each file, and send the command you are running (if you are able to)

Answer (score 1):

The error sounds like your sfdx isn't installed correctly, you may have to reinstall. Or maybe you had newlines in your command and they messed something up?

You need to read up about [`force:source:deploy`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_deploy) command, the `-p` parameter...

This is a decent example of what you can do. Bit boring, repetitive but deploys exactly these files and nothing more, not whole folders.

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -u prod -p "force-app/main/default/objects/MyObject__c/fields/Description__c.field-meta.xml,force-app/main/default/objects/MyObject__c/fields/Amount__c.field-meta.xml,force-app/main/default/objects/MyObject__c/fields/Quantity__c.field-meta.xml,force-app/main/default/classes/MyObjectTriggerHandler.cls" -l RunSpecifiedTests -r "SomeTestClass" --verbose --loglevel fatal
```

There are also some cool sfdx plugins that will generate the xml file for you based on difference between 2 commits? Search list at https://github.com/mshanemc/awesome-sfdx-plugins